# Java find a string in text not working

Tags: java, string, text, find

This is a sample `.txt` file:

```
item1
item2
myString
item3
item4
```

I created a class to find a string in a `.txt` file:

```
public static String lineToFind;
public static boolean lineFound;
public static void findLine() throws IOException{
    try {
        lineFound=true;
        fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Franky/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication5/src/Punteggi/squadre");
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        lineToFind = "myString";
        String strline;
        while(br.readLine()!=null)
        if(br.readLine()!=lineToFind){
        lineaFound=false;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LeggiDaFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

this class is used in another class, if the lineaFound=false;

```
private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    findLine();
    if(lineFound=true){
    callFunction1();
    }
    if(lineFound=false){
    callFunction2();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that `callFunction2()` is never called, even if "`myString`" is not included in the file. Easily the "`false`" condition never happens even if it has to happen!
Thanks

Comment: You should use `.equals` for string comparison instead of `==` or `!=`

Comment: lineFound...
i translated my Italian code in English code sorry...

Comment: BTW: The DataInputStream doesn't do anything. I would remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
String strline;
 while(br.readLine()!=null)
    if(br.readLine()!=lineToFind){
    lineaFound=false;
  }
```

You are reading line twice.  And you can't do string comparison on string without using equals...

```
String strline;
while(strline = br.readLine()!=null)
    if(strline.equals(lineToFind)){
    lineaFound=false;
}
```

There is also the assignment issue from another answer.

Answer (score 3):

`lineFound=false` is an assignment, not a test.

Try

```
if (!lineFound)
```

or

```
if (lineFound == false)
```

instead of

```
if (lineFound=false)
```

and similarly for `if (lineFound=true)`

Also, be aware of [auto-unboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) in Java when using `==` or `!=` with booleans.

```
Boolean b = possiblyNullOrABoolean();
if (b == false) {
  ...
}
```

The test with `==` has a very different meaning than `if (!b)` when the type of `b` is `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` not `=`.

```
 if(lineFound==true){
    callFunction1();
    }
    if(lineFound==false){
    callFunction2();
    }
```

You are also doing the string comparison incorrectly.

`if(br.readLine()!=lineToFind)` should be `if(br.readLine().equals(lineToFind))`

Answer (score 1):

But there are several serious other errors in your code.
For exaple, if not every second line pf the file matches the string, lineFound will come out false.

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside a `if( )` condition to be equated is to be with ' `==` ' and not '`=`'.

```
'=' is an assignment operator.  
'==' checks for the equivalence.
```

It should be

```
if (lineFound == false)
```

and so on for errors in same context.

Also, what is `LineaFound` ?

Change

```
LineaFound = false;
```

to

```
LineFound = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

`lineFound=true` with

`lineFound==true`

and `lineFound=false` with

`lineFound==false`

That is, use `==` ( comparison operator ) instead of `=` ( assignment operator )

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, despite the already mentioned `==` instead of `=`, and the use of `equals` to compare Strings, and only comparing every second line:

1 - The loop in `findLine` results in `lineaFound = false` if the **last line** of the file is not `"myString"`, no matter if some other line is "myString" (also if using `equals`).

```
    ...
    lineaFound = false;
    String strline;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (strLine.equals(lineToFind)) {
            lineaFound = true;
            break;  // we are done, exit the loop
        }
    }
    ...
```

2 - Why are you using a `DataInputStream`?  This is only needed to read data created by a `DataOutputStream`.